# Upload file (invoice) to existing order

Tags: orders, magento2.4, magento2.4.5, file-upload

Is it possible to add an externally generated invoice to an existing order record?

**The scenario is as follows:**
A company receives orders via a Magento 2.4 online shop.

The orders are further processed in an ERP system and the invoice is also generated there.

Now the company would like to make it accessible to the customer via his Magento account.

How could this kind of invoice upload be realized?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to add an externally generated invoice to an existing order record in Magento 2. You can achieve this by creating a custom module that allows customers to upload invoices through their Magento account.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @prachi! You misunderstood me though: I don't want the customer to upload an invoice, but the sales department staff.

Comment: @Pixelrocker okay